# ¿Cómo hacer un stack de matrices en c++?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy usando la librería

```
#include <stack>
```

La he usado de la siguiente forma:

```
stack<int> p1;
```

Esto para tener una pila de enteros, pero no sé cómo guardar en la pila matrices de **4x4**, lo intenté de la siguiente forma pero no se puede.

```
stack<int [2][2]>;
```

Comment: Hay un **error muy grave** en mi respuesta. Por favor, vuelve a mirarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por tu pregunta, veo que estás usando C++98. Así que tienes varias opciones:

#### 1. Cambia a C++11 o superior.

En esa versión, `stack< int[2][2] >` es perfectamente válido.

Es la solución que te recomiendo. Obtendrás mayor rendimiento en general, y te permite hacer lo que quieres sin problemas.

## EDITO

Como comenta @PaperBirdMaster, esto es **FALSO**.

C++11 permite *declarar* `stack< int[2][2] >`, **pero ...** cualquier intento de usarlo genera un **error**:

```
int data[2][2];
stack< int[2][2] > map;
map.push( data );
```

> `error: parenthesized initializer in array new`
> `sorry, unimplemented: cannot initialize multi-dimensional array with initializer`

Por lo tanto, esta solución es **incorrecta**, siendo necesario utilizar otra de las propuestas.

## FIN DE EDICIÓN

#### 2. Usa ::std::vector< >

No es lo mismo, pero te puede valer perfectamente:

```
stack< vector< int > >
```

Obtienes la ventaja de que no estás limitado a `[2][2]`. Un vector puede contener cualquier número de elementos.

#### 3. Crea tu propia clase.

Conlleva algo mas de trabajo, pero también es posible. Puedes usar plantillas, o crear una clase específica.

No es tan *complicado* como parece:

```
struct mydata {
  int data[2][2];
  int *operator[]( int c ) { return data[c]; }
};

mydata d;

d[1][1] = 0;

stack< mydata > s;
```

Puedes aprovechar y añadir funcionalidad, como comprobar que no te pasas del tamaño del *arreglo*.

#### 4. Guarda *punteros*

En lugar de `stack< int[2][2] >`, puedes hacer `stack< int * >`.

Es **la peor solución**. Tienes que encargarte de toda la gestión de memoria por ti mismo.

Pero servir, sirve.

Comment: No he podido comprobar que una pila de arreglos multidimensionales funcione en C++11, de hecho lo estoy probando con C++14 y GCC y CLang [fallan](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j4sHsHAAQ5AvbEcD) al compilar.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster tienes razón; edito la respuesta. `#include <stack> std::stack< int[2][2] > map;` no da errores con `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c`, **pero ...**, si intento `map.push( ALGO )`, entonces **si** da error.

Comment: piensa que en las plantillas puedes tener código no válido en funciones miembro y compilar perfectamente... siempre y cuando no uses el código no válido xD

Comment: Lo que me extraña es el *mensajito* de error: `sorry, unimplemented: cannot initialize multi-dimensional array with initializer`. :-? *Curioso*.